# Python: How do I exclude docstrings in code coverage reporting?

Tags: python, regex, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm trying to figure out how to edit the `.coveragerc` file so that docstrings aren't included in the percentage of code coverage. 
This is what I've tried:

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    """
```

and I've also tried

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    \"\"\"
```

but I still get shown near 100% code coverage for a script that is mainly made of docstrings.

Answer (score 3):

Ah nevermind, my mistake, it turns out that they are already ignored. It's just that I was using the Pycharm editor, which highlights these docstring lines in green but they do not actually contribute to the percentage of code coverage